# Write a bash script that displays, for each file given as an argument, the line that appears the most

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, array

Write a bash script that displays, for each file given as an argument, the line that appears the most. The display will be made in descending order of the number of occurrences.

I'm not sure how to write both the line and the number of times it appears in an array (that I would later sort)

Edit:

I've changed what I did before and now I can find the line that appears the most and the number of times it appears for each file. But I don't know how to sort them

Edit: I've made some more changes. Now the codes does what I wanted it to do, but is there a better way of doing this?

```
    #!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
        echo "Input at least one argument"
        exit 1
fi

declare -a my_array



K=0
for FILE in $*
do
        line=$(sort $FILE | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -n 1 | sed -E 's/^ *[0-9]+ //g')
        max=$(sort $FILE | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -n 1 | awk '{print $1}')
        echo $max
        echo $line
        my_array[$K]=$line
        my_array1[$K]=$max
        K=$(($K+1))
done


result=$(( COUNTER=0
         while [  $COUNTER -lt "${#my_array[@]}" ]; do
            echo ${my_array1[$COUNTER]} ${my_array[$COUNTER]}
             let COUNTER=COUNTER+1
         done ) | sort -r)
echo "$result"
```

Example input

file1:

```
one two three
four five
one two three
```

file2:

```
nine nine 
eight seven
nine
eight seven
eight seven
```

Then:

```
$ ./exercise.sh file1 file2
3 eight seven 
2 one two three
```

Comment: Both [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html#Arrays) and [awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) have associative arrays that allow you to count lines like this: `linearray[line]++` (that's awk syntax). When you have counted all lines of a file, step through the array and find the line with the largest number. awk: `for (line in linearray) if (linearray[line] > max) ... `.

Comment: "I'm not sure how to write both the line and the number of times it appears in an array" -- `sort` and/or `uniq`. Also, you should [edit] your post to include a sample input and output, and show what you've built so far -- or split this into multiple questions.

Comment: An often used idiom is `sort | uniq -c | sort -n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're nearly there. You can sort the output of the loop (and remove the spaces at the beginning of the lines):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Input at least one argument" >&2
    exit 1
fi

for file; do
    sort "$file" | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -n1
done | sort -rn | sed 's/^ *//'
```

Other changes:

- Output error message to stderr
- Use `for file; do` or the longer version `for file in "$@"; do` to loop over the positional parameters
- Quote the variable

Comment: Thank you. I really overcomplicated the problem. Can I ask what is the last sed doing?

Comment: It just removes the spaces at the beginning of the lines which were added by `uniq -c`.